# Which hosts support Unicode in International Domain Names?

Tags: unicode

I recently registered some Chinese character domain names at the .hk registrar.  I was hoping to host them at 1and1 but am getting nowhere fast.  Their system appears to struggle with the unicode characters and ignores punycode.

I was wondering if anyone has experience of good hosts who support unicode domain names?

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried simply entering the [punycode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Punycode) version of the domain names? This is what is actually used when DNS entry is resolved.

Comment: 1and1 doesn't seem to like punycode at all. And their helpdesk doesn't understand the question.

Answer (score 1):

[Bluehost](http://www.bluehost.com/cgi/info/hosting_features) seems to do what you need.